# Dash App in Shopify fails to load dash components

Tags: python, flask, shopify, plotly-dash

I have built a DASH app and deployed it in server and it works fine but when I try to embed it in Shopify dashboard, it fails to load dash components, can anyone help me with this!

Here’s how I’ve embedded it

I’ve built a dash app which works fine both in local and in development server but throws an error while embedding in Shopify

code:

```
<div class="dashboard">
var cloud_url = "https://yyy.zzzz.com/";
$(".dashboard").load(cloud_url);

</div>
```

and here’s the error I get

> GET
>   https://apps.abc.com/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react@15.4.2.min.js?v=0.21.0&m=1552054944
>   (404 Not Found)

FYI - My dash app URL is different from my Shopify app and for some reason it appends to Shopify URL and not the other

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution, for a time being I have embedded with the help of an iframe concept @KostasMouratidis

Comment: mine wasn't with Shopify but I did end up solving it; it was, too, that the dash app URL was different (I used Werkzeug's `DispatcherMiddleware` to add Dash to a Flask app). This was the fix: `app = Dash(__name__, requests_pathname_prefix="/modeling/", assets_external_path="http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/")` where `modeling` was the subdomain (i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/modeling`) and the external path had Flask's static files.